# Magento layered navigation incredibly slow

Tags: performance, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I have some issue with performance of **layered navigation default module**.

I have 10k products but in category I want to filter there is 60.

Unfortunatley filtering by one attribute last 12 seconds (after  many optimizations)

Every tweak and performance tip I found basically said

> Don't use layered navigation, it slows down your magento a lot.

I have hosted magento on quite fast SSD based hosting with prety big amount of available memory.

- Is there a good approach to speed up layered navigation a lot?
- How it should be done?
- How you guys are doing it?
- Are paid modules for layered navigation speed things up?
- Is there some kind of workaround I should use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also in same bottleneck, you got any solution?
if yes please help.

Comment: I spent  weeks trying solve my issue. Finally I abandon Magento. Can't believe people uses it and feel happy about it.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento, for each attribute that is marked as filterable, it will make a call to getAllOptions() of attribute source model. Even if there are no filter results for it, it will invoke attribute option collection load. A possible solution and other optimization tips are described here:

http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/ivanchepurnyi/making-magento-flying-like-a-rocket-a-set-of-valuable-tips-for-developers

Also, make sure the layered navigation block is cached ( many simple extensions just skip this)

Try solr based layered navigation as well.

Server performance is also important.

Comment: I already seen this solution. Im curious particulary about layered navigation to fly like a rocket so its quite unapplyable I would appreciate some advices for it. Also i don't  entirely understand the sentence "many simple extensions just skip this". Can you give example of such extension? I would like to solve my problem by refactoring code rather than cache. Do you have exaple usage of some kind of crawler to fill the cache?